Magento 2 Carding attack guest cart order placed even if we disable guest cart using REST API
I am using Magento 2.4.7-p1 hackers are trying to place order using guest cart REST API carding attacks
tried cloudflare , rate limit magento and captcha also, but no use in braintree created so many rules, but no use.
As per our analysis, this request will be used while making orders from APIs not from the front end if we disable this API from the code level under this file.
vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml
Code to comment is below.
###############################################
################################################
disabled above code still carding attack is running.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/rest-default-V1-guest-carts-open-to-DDOS/td-p/421447
can any one please tell how to stop guest order rest api

They can try as many times as they want, if you upgrade your magento 2 to latest security patch releases...they will be blocked by Content Security Policies.
More details in CSP ASPB Security Patch

already, i am using latest version and enabled csp
